# Creating new object in a submethod apparently doesn't pass the reference

Tags: java, reference, new-operator

i am currently working on a java project, which implements the dijkstra-algorithm.
I've got some code which looks similar to this

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
      Graph myGraph = null;
      execute(myGraph);
    }

    private static void execute(Graph graph){
      while(!quit){
      doCommand(graph);
    }}


    doCommand(Graph graph){
      if(command == n){
        graph = new Graph(size); }}
```

In my programm i can enter a few commands, for example n 5 which means that the programm should create a new Graph with the 5 nodes.
Now my problem is, that after entering for example n 5, it's still null.
In my opinion, myGraph should receive a new reference after the n-command, but apparently it doesn't and i don't get why.
Btw, the line graoh = new Graph(size); is definitely executed. That's not the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does not allow you to reseat references since it is pass by *value*. What this means is that references are also passed by *value*. When you did `graph = new Graph(size)`, all you did was make the local reference (which is a copy of the reference passed in from `main`) point to the new instance of `Graph`. `graph` inside `main` is still `null`.

A workaround might be to have `doCommand` return an instance of `Graph`, or perhaps use a static instance of `Graph` (since it appears that all your methods are static methods). Another option would be to encapsulate `graph` inside some other class as property, which means all methods inside the class will have access to it.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot that Java don't really uses Call-by-Reference :-)

Answer (score 1):

Aliasing can be confusing here.

passing an object into a method creates a new alias(another name that refers to the same object). when the state of the object is changed, that's reflected in all aliases.

Assigning to the variable breaks aliasing. after the line

```
graph = new Graph(size);
```

the variable graph points to the new object, not the object it was originally assigned.
This change is local to the variable, and breaks aliasing. so graph no longer references the same object as myGraph.

Answer (score 0):

In your method `doCommand` you only assign new graph object to local reference `graph`, but since it is local to the method, this change has no effect on your main `myGraph` reference, which always remains null according to :

```
Graph myGraph = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to spend some time studying basic procedural logic.  Your main() SETS graph to null JUST BEFORE it calls execute() -- of course it's null when that method starts execution, it could not be anything else.

If you want a number you enter on a command line to be used you have to put it to use.  If you enter "5", for instance, it will appear as a string in args[0].  If you want to do something that number of times, you have to convert it to an integer (after confirming that the string represents one!) and then put that value to use in some (presumably) integer variable.

Comment: I know that i set the graph to null. I only did because i can't give a not initialised object to execute(). The problem i had was, that the graph was still null after i executed the n-command. And of course this isn't the whole code, i there is also much other stuff which for example converts the input to integer and so on, but I thought that this isn't needed to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this code!

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Graph myGraph = new Graph();
    doCommand(myGraph);
    System.out.println(myGraph);
}
private static void doCommand(Graph myGraph){
    myGraph = new Graph();
    System.out.println(myGraph);
}
```

You will notice that both System.out.println statements will print different object references.

This is because when you call the doCommand method and pass the value of the reference of myGraph, and then you create a new object Graph() in the doCommand method, the local variable myGraph (inside doCommand) will point to a new object, but that will not change the value of myGraph in main().

However if you do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Graph myGraph = new Graph();
    myGraph = doCommand(myGraph);
    System.out.println(myGraph);
}
private static Graph doCommand(Graph myGraph){
    myGraph = new Graph();
    System.out.println(myGraph);
    return myGraph;
}
```

Both println statements will print the same object references. This is because you are returning the value of the reference of myGraph in doCommand to myGraph in main.